# WPF ControlTemplate styling not showing in build mode

Tags: wpf, vb.net, visual-studio-2017

For my current application, first time in WPF, the only thing left to do is style my buttons. The problem is that the styling I apply does show up in the designer, but once I build the application the styling is not shown.

I copied the example button style from the walkthrough [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/controls/walkthrough-create-a-button-by-using-xaml) into my application.xaml:

```
<Application x:Class="Application"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="clr-namespace:VideoManager"
StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml"
ShutdownMode="OnMainWindowClose">
<Application.Resources>
    <!--Define a template that creates a gradient-colored button.-->
    <LinearGradientBrush x:Key="GrayBlueGradientBrush" StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="1,1">
        <GradientStop Color="DarkGray" Offset="0" />
        <GradientStop Color="#CCCCFF" Offset="0.5" />
        <GradientStop Color="DarkGray" Offset="1" />
    </LinearGradientBrush>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource GrayBlueGradientBrush}" />
        <Setter Property="Width" Value="80" />
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="10" />
    </Style>
</Application.Resources>
```

And I created a temporary window for testing:

```
<Window x:Class="Settings"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:VideoManager"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="Settings" Height="450" Width="800">
<Grid>
    <Button Content="Button" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="145,46,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75"/>
    <Button Content="Button" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="145,121,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75"/>

</Grid>
```

Like I said, in the designer view everything looks just as ugly as it should be but once built the styles somehow arent preserved.
I also tried the same code in a new project and there it did work.

What settings could be preventing the button layout from showing up in build mode?

Comment: I guess XAML **File properties** such as `Build Action` and `Copy To Output Directory`

Comment: That was indeed the problem. I completely forgot that at some point I set Application.xaml build action to ´none´ as part of a retrospectively ill-advised attempt to handle some application level events. Thank you so much!

Comment: glad to help :) you can post your findings as an answer for future readers.